# What does "OP" mean, as in "massively OP version of force telekinesis"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the answer to another question, user Daft suggests that something is "a massively OP version of force telekinesis".  What does OP mean or stand for?
(All users should take the hint that you should not use abbreviations in your answers; it defeats the purpose of answering a question if you just cause confusion.)

Comment: It's internet slang for "overpowered". Nothing to do with Star Wars. (answering in a comment since I'm not sure if this question is on-topic)

Comment: You should go ask this on the SF&F meta site.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Well, no, it's not a question about how SF&F.SE works, so it wouldn't make much sense there either. ELU.SE is the site where it might be accepted.

Comment: In this instance, Ixrec is right; mainly comes from (video) games. Another one used a lot here is "Original Poster", refering to the person who asked the question in the first place

Comment: @Ixrec It seems obviously off-topic to me, since it's not a word specific to a work of science fiction or fantasy, or generally to the two genres. Asking what a specific, made up word from an actual work meant would be fine, but that's not what this question does.

Comment: Also, while I appreciate that you don't yet have the necessary reputation to do so (and also appreciate that the downvotes on this question move you further from that goal), a comment on the post that uses a term you don't understand would be the best means of asking these kinds of questions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it means "Overpowered", meaning a level above or stronger than force telekinesis in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the context you're using, the term means "overpowered".

It gained a lot of exposure with the rise in popularity of MMORPG-style video games (though I don't think it originated there) as a way to describe some combination of characters or character abilities that were not "balanced" properly. Using an **OP** character or move gave you a major advantage over anyone not using it.

In video game terms, **OP** is usually implicitly bad, because it unbalances the game; everyone will quickly start using only that move/character to the exclusion of all else. That typically leads the game developers to **nerf** the character/move.

Outside of the video game context, an **OP** thing is a much more powerful version of some previously known thing. There's frequently an implication at **OP** things are *too* powerful -- more powerful than they need to be or than it makes sense for them to be, within the context of a given fictional universe.

In the example you gave, "Force Telekinesis" is a thing we have seen used in the *Star Wars* films before; in the most recent film, a character appears to use it to do something that is significantly more powerful than any previous example, thus it's "OP Force Telekinesis."